# MonoTouch: How to protect my application

Tags: .net, ios, encryption, xamarin.ios, dotfuscator

I used Dotfuscator to protect my application from reverse engineering I encrypted the dll files in windows application, but how can I do it in OSX/MonoTouch?

Extract the dll from ipa, then confuse the dlls in windows, and repack the encrypted dlls into IPA, then publish it to appstore?

Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Foremost you need to remember that iOS does not allow **JIT** (just in time) compiling. This means everything needs to go thru the **AOT** (ahead of time) compiler.

This results that all the IL code from your assemblies is being converted into native ARM (v6, v7 and/or thumb) instructions **and** that the IL is **not required** anymore.

This means that, when you're building for `Release|iPhone`, the IL code will be removed from your assemblies. Since it's strip'ed away it won't be present (to be decompiled) in the application you publish.

**NOTES**

- the assemblies will still be inside the application **because** the metadata is still required (e.g. `System.Reflection` needs it). So symbols names and resources files won't be mangled/encrypted like obfuscators generally do;
- You can disassemble ARM assembly (that would be true even if you obfuscated the assemblies before the AOT compilation) but it's **much** harder to understand (and get back to C#) than IL is.
- Extracting the assemblies from the IPA and procesing them will break **at least** the application's signature (you can re-sign it). It will also **likely** break a lot of other things (since the code will refer to names/structures that might have changed). I do not think this will work (but it depends on the options you would use from your obfuscator).

Comment: thanks. Yes, I understand it's AOT compiler in monotouch. but I got a  mistake with it , because yesterday I put the dlls(from ipa package) in the reflector tools, I saw a lot of c# code. Now I review it , it's just a method stub, no any business logic code. thanks a lot, thanks to xamarin team which bring such a good product.