# Processing a Xamarin.iOS executable before native compilation

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, mdtool

How can we hook into the Xamarin.iOS `mdtool` build in order to modify the app executable's MSIL before it is compiled to native? (Obfuscation is one scenario that needs this ability; there are likely other scenarios as well.)

Answer (score 2):

`mdtool` simply runs a solution (or project) build. What's defined inside the projects will be executed from the tool. E.g. You can define **Custom Commands** in your project, adding operations:

- before build;
- build;
- after build;
- before clean;
- clean;
- after clean; and
- custom commands

Note that obfuscation [is not very helpful (or needed)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9667265/220643) for Xamarin.iOS applications since you are **not** shipping the **IL** of your application (as everything is AOT'ed) as part of your release (non-debug) builds.