# Objective C vs Xamarin iOS C# obfuscation

Tags: objective-c, .net, xamarin.ios, obfuscation

Is it really required to obfuscate Xamarin iOS code ?

What is difference between code written in Objective C vs C# Xamarin obfuscation?

I have gone through lot of post but answer is not clear.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really required to obfuscate xamarin iOS code ?

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9667494/220643) I provided to [MonoTouch: How to protect my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667265/monotouch-how-to-protect-my-application/9667494#9667494) should cover everything. If not then you'll need to be more specific in your question.

> What is difference between code written in Obective C vs C# Xamarin obfuscation?

That's not a valid comparison, i.e. ObjC does not compare with obfuscation *and* Xamarin does not offer (by itself) obfuscation.

However if you compare both ObjC compiler and Xamarin's AOT compiler code then you'll find that both produce native ARM[64] binaries.

In most cases developers use obfuscations tools (on .NET) because they ship the IL (intermediate code) with their application. That's required for a JIT (just in time compiler to work) but **not** for a AOT (ahead of time compiler) which Xamarin.iOS uses.